# Responsive web design, scaling images; save bandwidth?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have been reading a couple of topics about making responsive web sites and then the problems it comes with when using images, as apparently it can take up a lot of bandwidth (as you would have one image which would fit on a desktop which could be 1080px, and then scale it down to be on a mobile which might only be 300px but it would still be the same file size as the larger one)

My question is, within the interchangeable CSS for the different layouts, can't you define an image within that? So that say, you have 2 @media enquiries, you would then have 2 images of different sizes to cater to the layouts which would then take up less bandwidth (example, you have a 1080px for the desktop site and an image which is 300px for the mobile site which would then take up a lot less bandwidth)

Is this practice wrong? Or is this a viable fix? Could someone explain how this wouldn't solve the issue, as I believe it would? I would like to make some responsive sites, but that are kind to bandwidth

Comment: I don't think there's really a need for multiple images, the smaller devices have higher dpi.

Comment: You have a new attribute for img tag showing up : `srcset` . http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/ , webkit seems to understand part of it  http://www.webkit.org/demos/srcset/

Comment: There isn't a need to save bandwidth on most sites, so you should probably just use one larger image. But if you wanted to do multiple images, you could use the jquery `.width()` function to find the width and then use AJAX to get the smaller image.

Comment: @DavidCorbin There might not be for desktop, but I believe there is for mobile, as some people will be on a limit bandwidth from their providers

Comment: @GCyrillus Thank you for those links, I will read them :)

Comment: @MysMelody That is true if your targeted viewers are a lot of mobile users. If that's true, you could just create a special mobile site optimized for them.

Comment: @DavidCorbin , well tell my mobile and my home slow connection that there is no need :) , i have to deal with this everyday, and some website , nevers sees me , cause image and too many script loading ...

Comment: @GCyrillus That could be a problem for some people, but most have fast enough internet that a single image loading should not be a problem.

Comment: Seeing some research, especially in developing countries, they only have access to mobile phones, as they're getting donated from the richer countries, and this is their only access to the internet. While they might not be the customers you're targeting, it's about trying to consider everyone and not restrict your web presence but to allow everyone access as best as possible, as web development should be about inclusion and not alienation... Is a thought I'm having :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use media queries and set the image as `background-image` on a `div` element maybe.

Ex here: http://jsfiddle.net/qsByJ/

```
@media all and (min-width: 520px) {
  #demo{
      background-image:url(http://unreasonableatsea.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/demo-logo-large.png);
        height:439px;
        width:660px;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 520px) {
  #demo{
      background-image:url(http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000043575260-xlr304-original.jpg?164b459);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:282px;
        width:425px;
  }
}
```

This way you can serve a different image for a different device.

Some points why you should consider using different images:

- on older devices a big image can crash the website or make it move really slow since the memory is small.
- if you have more images on the page, performance will be affected since on some devices, on every draw, the images must be scaled down.
- if you have a lot of images (social websites for example) the bandwidth consumption will be a lot larger.

Comment: Ahh yes this is more of the answer I was hoping to get :)! Thank you. May I ask though if it is on a mobile, will it try to load both images and then display one of them, or will it just load the one it needs based on the @media inquiry?

Comment: As far as I know, it will load the one it needs.

Answer (score 0):

This I think is a great question!

I have been having this exact problem myself. After a number of days of searching around I have managed to find a perfect solution.

Take a look at sprite sheets for images. This is where all your images are contained within a single image and then that only requires one image request to be sent. Therefor saving a lot of bandwidth.

What is even better is that if you make the sprite sheet at a high resolution and make it so it scales down dependant on screen size no pixelation will occur, giving you the desired results.

I hope this helps!

Comment: When you say it scales down, does it still have the same file size as the larger image? As what you say sounds like the original problem, of having a large image and then trying to scale it down, but that still means it could be a large image (especially for retina-ready display). Or am I thinking of the bandwidth problem wrong, and the issue is that the image requests are causing a suck of bandwidth rather than a single image, as if you have multiple CSS sheets with defined images it will try to load all into the cache while only displaying the relevant ones?

Comment: Oki doki - If you have a number of smaller different images this will significantly increase the bandwidth compared to one single large image. This is why sprite sheets are now becoming more and more popular, due to a single http request instead of sending a new request for each individual image. :)

Comment: Sprite sheets had been popular for a decade or more. The advantage with them is that you only make one request instead of many (save time used for requests) and that you use less bandwidth since you don't have the send `headers` (the bandwidth gain is not all that big).